# How do I watermark an image?

Tags: php, gd

I have a jpg file that i want to merge another image png file on it. I am not sure how to implement this using php?

Comment: That's great. Care to provide us with some details and some existing code? What have you tried?

Comment: you should change title of this question to "Watermarking image using gd and php"

Comment: @Arshpreet can you please select the right answer ? if you believe none of these answers helped, you could post in whatever things you did to get it done and select that to be your best answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use gd's **imagecopy** function.

This function is used to copy a portion of image from source to the destination

```
imagecopy ( 
           $dst_im ,   // destination image (resource), imagecreatefrom(gif|jpg|png)
           $src_im ,   // destination image (resource), imagecreatefrom(gif|jpg|png) 
           $dst_x ,    // x cordinate in destination where u want the new obj placed
           $dst_y ,    // y cordinate in destination where u want the new obj placed
           $src_x ,    // x cordinate in source from wher u want the new obj placed
           $src_y ,    // y cordinate in source from where u want the new obj placed
           $src_w ,    // the width of the object to copy
           $src_h      // the height of the object to copy
);
```

As pointed in the comment in the above code, you will have to create an image resource for both destination and source.

Typically done using

```
 $src = imagecreatefromjpg('image.jpg');
 $dst = imagecreatefromjpg('watermark');
```

The remaining portions are just simple co-ordinates.

Also don't forget to visit [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example on hot do watermarking using GD:

```
const CORNER_TOP_LEFT       = 1;
const CORNER_TOP_RIGHT      = 2;
const CORNER_BOTTOM_LEFT    = 3;
const CORNER_BOTTOM_RIGHT   = 4;

$backgroundImagePath = "img/stamp.png";
$corner=CORNER_BOTTOM_RIGHT;
$alpha=60

$img_res=@imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$img_info=getimagesize($backgroundImagePath);

switch ($corner){
    case CORNER_TOP_LEFT:
        if(!imagecopymerge ($this->imageRes, $img_res, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img_info[0], $img_info[1], $alpha)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to make stamp!");
        }
        break;
    case CORNER_TOP_RIGHT:
        if(!imagecopymerge ($this->imageRes, $img_res, $this->info[0]-$img_info[0], 0, 0, 0, $img_info[0], $img_info[1], $alpha)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to make stamp!");
        }
        break;
    case CORNER_BOTTOM_LEFT:
        if(!imagecopymerge ($this->imageRes, $img_res, 0, $this->info[1]-$img_info[1], 0, 0, $img_info[0], $img_info[1], $alpha)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to make stamp!");
        }
        break;
    case CORNER_BOTTOM_RIGHT:
        if(!imagecopymerge ($this->imageRes, $img_res, $this->info[0]-$img_info[0], $this->info[1]-$img_info[1], 0, 0, $img_info[0], $img_info[1], $alpha)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to make stamp!");
        }
        break;
}

imagejpeg($img_res, "/path/to/save/image.jpg", 100);
```

Comment: I want to merge jpeg file created from php like here $filename = "pic.php" i want to use php because the pic.php generate random pic and i want to merge pic on it.??

Comment: It's unclean how your random images is being generated. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: take example of captcha i generete using image ttf function and then i wanted to add watermark to it

Comment: So the line `$img_res=@imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);` creates resource from image file. Assuming that you already generated some image assign it to `$img_res` in above code.